# How to Parameterize xpath in True client script

Tags: xpath, loadrunner

This is my scenario - I have a grid in the application . The grid contains Filters with check box . When check box is selected the filter will be applied on the application . 
I have written the xpath to select a checkbox (ex: //div[text()='FirstFilter']/div) this will select the FirstFilter check box .

I want to parameterize  the  Xpath such that if any filter name is given that filter check box should be selected.
I am unable to find options to paarmaeterize the xpath in trueclient .

Any suggestions please .

Comment: Have answered the question, please check and let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a String filterName and then using that, can parameterise the xpath like:

```
String filterName = null;       
// Insert the value in the filterName according to your requirements
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()="+filterName+"']/div"));
```